# How to return two function at once?

Tags: bash, return

I'd like to write function `abort` that do some staff and then aborts calling function. Is it possible?

The goal is to emulate `set -e` but on function level - returning from function instead of exiting entire script. So I need to put trap on the `ERR` which would kill function.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize subshells to allow them to "take the hit" when a program exits non-zero.

Wrap the function call in parentheses to execute it in a subshell. Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

function abort {
    set -e
    exit 1
}

function f {
    echo "Hello"
    abort
    echo "Will not be called"
}

(f)
echo "After f"
```

If you want your `f` always to be "abortable", wrap the whole definition in parentheses and then you don't need them each time when calling:

```
function f {(
    echo "Hello"
    abort
    echo "Will not be called"
)}
```

Comment: You can use just `f() ( ... )`.

Comment: Could subshell set variables in the caller script?

Comment: No, variables can only be set downward in a caller hierarchy.

Comment: This is a tempting solution, but check the behavior of `if (f); then echo after f; fi`

Comment: That is, check that behavior after you've done `trap abort ERR`, rather than calling `abort` explicitly.  `set -e` will not behave as you want in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want a trap on RETURN:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

cleanup()  {
        echo 'foo invoked cleanup'
}

foo() {
        trap cleanup return
        test "$1" = fail && return 3 # instead of abort
        trap : return # clear the trap to avoid calling cleanup
        return 0
}
foo
echo foo returned $?
foo fail
echo foo returned $?
$ ./a.sh
foo returned 0
foo invoked cleanup
foo returned 3
```

Comment: I need to put a number of lines that could fails and I would prefer to avoid `cmd && return` boilerplate. Under normal conditions I would use `set -e`, but this time I don't need to exit program, but to return from function

Comment: That is tempting, but `set -e` is not reliable.  `cmd && return` is best practice.